# python recode csv with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am a beginner in python. 
I need to recode a CSV file:

```
unique_id,pid,Age
1,1,1
1,2,3
2,1,5
2,2,6
3,1,6
3,2,4
3,3,6
3,4,1
3,5,4
4,1,6
4,2,5
```

The condition is: for each [unique_id], if there is any [Age]==6, then put a value 1 in the corresponding rows of with a [pid]=1, others should be 0.

the output csv will look like this:

```
unique_id,pid,Age,recode
1,1,1,0
1,2,3,0
2,1,5,1
2,2,6,0
3,1,6,1
3,2,4,0
3,3,6,0
3,4,1,0
3,5,4,0
4,1,6,1
4,2,5,0
```

I was using numpy: like follwoing:

```
import numpy
input_file1 = "data.csv"
input_folder = 'G:/My Drive/'
Her_HH =pd.read_csv(input_folder + input_file1)
Her_HH['recode'] = numpy.select([Her_PP['Age']==6,Her_PP['Age']<6], [1,0], default=Her_HH['recode'])

Her_HH.to_csv('recode_elderly.csv', index=False)
```

but it does not put value 1 in where [pid] is 1. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't post images of data, use text so others can reproduce it easily

Comment: Ok. I am putting text.

Comment: also use library name instead of abbreviation - Numpy. This makes it easier to find.

Comment: What is Her_HH?

Comment: Why is there a `1` on this line in expected output: `2,1,5,1`?

Comment: Do you **have** to use numpy?

Comment: @HarshalParekh not, not really. I was trying with numpy select. But I donot have to use numpy. anything is fine.

Comment: @hpaulj this is how I read the csv: Her_HH =pd.read_csv(input_folder + input_file2)

Comment: @Tashaho, in future posts, please post all the relevant code and variables referred

Comment: @HarshalParekh added.

Comment: `Her_HH['recode'] = ...` did look more like a `pandas` than a pure `numpy` expression.  A `pandas` tag is important; more so than the `csv` source.  What result did you get?

Comment: That `default=Her_HH['recode']` is wrong, since you haven't created a 'recode' column yet.  You test 'Age`' but not 'pid' or do any grouping on id.

Comment: You need to start with a grouping, `Her_HH.groupby('unique_id')`

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. It isn't clear to me what exactly the issue is here.

Comment: @AMC, dataframes are always called `df` :)

Comment: @hpaulj Pardon?

Comment: @HarshalParekh, you gave a solution earlier but removed later. Can you add that solution again, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for test if at least one match by [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html), chain mask for test `1` with `&` for bitwise AND and last cast output to integers

```
#sorting if necessary
df = df.sort_values('unique_id')

m1 = df.assign(test=df['Age'] == 6).groupby('unique_id')['test'].transform('any')
```

Another idea for get groups with `6` is filter them with `unique_id` and [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
m1 = df['unique_id'].isin(df.loc[df['Age'] == 6, 'unique_id'])
```

---

```
m2 = df['pid'] == 1

df['recode'] = (m1 & m2).astype(int)
print (df)
    unique_id  pid  Age  recode
0           1    1    1       0
1           1    2    3       0
2           2    1    5       1
3           2    2    6       0
4           3    1    6       1
5           3    2    4       0
6           3    3    6       0
7           3    4    1       0
8           3    5    4       0
9           4    1    6       1
10          4    2    5       0
```

EDIT:

For check groups with no match 6 in Age column is possible filter by inverted mask by `~` and if want only all unique rows by `unique_id` values add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df[~m1])
   unique_id  pid  Age
0          1    1    1
1          1    2    3

df1 = df[~m1].drop_duplicates('unique_id')
print (df1)
   unique_id  pid  Age
0          1    1    1
```

Comment: I used this:
df['recode'] = (df.assign(test=df['Age'] == 6).groupby('unique_id')['test'].transform('any') & (df['pid']==1)).astype(int)

Comment: your code worked fine for me while I tried it the test data, I proved here. However, while I tried with the real data, (which has more than 210 thousand rows), it gives 1 in every recode, for every [pid]=1 where there was any age 6 or not. But for the test data, it worked fine. I did double checked everything.

Comment: @Tashaho I guess problem is in 'hidden' groups. It means one part of same rows group is in start of dataframe, another somewhere in middle of data. So you can sorting data before my solution by `df = df.sort_values('unique_id')`

Comment: @jesrael, I tried sorting for both of your solution(assign and isin), but still, it gives 1 in every recode, for every [pid]=1 where there was any age 6 or not.

Comment: @Tashaho - Are data confidental? Because it seems some data related issue if data in sample working nice.

Comment: @Tashaho - You can also check rows with groups where is no 6 value in `Age` column, for solution is added `EDIT` to answer.

Comment: @jesrael.. no, data is not confidential.

Comment: @Tashaho - Is possible share data?

Comment: can I email you?

Comment: @Tashaho - sure, my email is in my profile, run code for email

Comment: can you please tell me how to send email? I have been trying to find in your profile, but not found any.

Comment: @jesrael.. it worked. The unique id in my main data was not unique. I made it unique, and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This a bit clumsy, since I know `numpy` a lot better than `pandas`.

Load your csv sample into a dataframe:

```
In [205]: df = pd.read_csv('stack59885878.csv')                                                  
In [206]: df                                                                                     
Out[206]: 
    unique_id  pid  Age
0           1    1    1
1           1    2    3
2           2    1    5
3           2    2    6
4           3    1    6
5           3    2    4
6           3    3    6
7           3    4    1
8           3    5    4
9           4    1    6
10          4    2    5
```

Generate a `groupby` object based on the `unique_id` column:

```
In [207]: gps = df.groupby('unique_id')                                                          

In [209]: gps.groups                                                                             
Out[209]: 
{1: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 2: Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64'),
 3: Int64Index([4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64'),
 4: Int64Index([9, 10], dtype='int64')}
```

I've seen `pandas` ways for iterating on groups, but here's a list comprehension.  The iteration produce a tuple, with the id and a dataframe.  We want to test each group dataframe for 'Age' and 'pid' values:

```
In [211]: recode_values = [(gp['Age']==6).any() & (gp['pid']==1) for x, gp in gps]               
In [212]: recode_values                                                                          
Out[212]: 
[0    False
 1    False
 Name: pid, dtype: bool, 2     True
 3    False
 Name: pid, dtype: bool, 4     True
 5    False
 6    False
 7    False
 8    False
 Name: pid, dtype: bool, 9      True
 10    False
 Name: pid, dtype: bool]
```

The result is a list of Series, with a True where `pid` is 1 and there's a 'Age' 6 in the group.

Joining these Series with `numpy.hstack` produces a boolean array, which we can convert to an integer array:

```
In [214]: np.hstack(recode_values)                                                               
Out[214]: 
array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
        True, False])
In [215]: df['recode']=_.astype(int)            # assign that to a new column
In [216]: df                                                                                     
Out[216]: 
    unique_id  pid  Age  recode
0           1    1    1       0
1           1    2    3       0
2           2    1    5       1
3           2    2    6       0
4           3    1    6       1
5           3    2    4       0
6           3    3    6       0
7           3    4    1       0
8           3    5    4       0
9           4    1    6       1
10          4    2    5       0
```

Again, I think there's an idiomatic pandas way of joining those series.  But for now this works.

===

OK, the groupby object has an `apply`:

```
In [223]: def foo(gp): 
     ...:     return (gp['Age']==6).any() & (gp['pid']==1).astype(int) 
     ...:                                                                                        
In [224]: gps.apply(foo)                                                                         
Out[224]: 
unique_id    
1          0     0
           1     0
2          2     1
           3     0
3          4     1
           5     0
           6     0
           7     0
           8     0
4          9     1
           10    0
Name: pid, dtype: int64
```

And remove the multi-indexing with:

```
In [242]: gps.apply(foo).reset_index(0, True)                                                    
Out[242]: 
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     1
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    0
Name: pid, dtype: int64
In [243]: df['recode']=_     # and assign to recode
```

Lots of experimenting and learning here.